# Strange rsync behaviour I don't understand throught SMB/CIFS

Tags: rsync, cifs

When I mount a share CIFS share on my machine I can see the content in `/run/user/<user ID>/gvfs`. That may be because I use a Mate flavour of ubuntu.

In that case I cannot do:

```
rsync -av path/*  /run/user/<user ID>/gvfs/dest/
```

it display correctly  the list of file but copy doesn't append. however if I

```
cp -a path/*  /run/user/<user ID>/gvfs/dest/
```

copy really append and files are now on the share.

Is there something I can do so I can use rsync on the mounted share?

NB: destination samba server is an embeded device, a NETGEAR access point with an USB shared space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case, it appears that the destination filesystem is some kind of FAT, or vfat, so the creation of temporary file with the format `.filename-tmpnumber` used by rsync seems to be impossible. So the use of `--inplace` option of rsync helped me  for this. There were a second issue that seems to come from the delta algorithm that is inefficient on such a mount. I finally were able to overcome with the help of `--whole-file or short -W`

In the end, this works for me:

```
rsync -avWP --inplace --size-only --no-perms path/*  /run/user/<user ID>/gvfs/dest/
```